# Source Tree Crashing a second after start-up

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I previously had another account for bitbucket that source tree was using, but I got invited through an email I didn't use for it and decided to create a new account for it. After that, I opened up bitbucket and decided to delete all my old stuff on there. Immediately after I deleted the last thing, it froze for a second before crashing, and does so every time I open it now.

**The Error Log**

2022-09-05T12:52:40: LogHost: Initializing to normal mode

2022-09-05T12:52:41: LogHost: SuppressChangeNotifications was called (perhaps via AddRange), yet you do not

2022-09-05T12:52:41: LogHost: have a subscription to ShouldReset. This probably isn't what you want, as ItemsAdded

2022-09-05T12:52:41: LogHost: and friends will appear to 'miss' items

2022-09-05T12:52:41: Could not obtain git dir,  is not a git repo.

2022-09-05T12:52:42: VaultClient::ReadCredentials

Every other question I searched has people delete and reinstall or removing old updates or updating to new ones. None of it works, as it picks up my old profile/account I used and crashes regardless. Any help on solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question will just be for my fellow newbs who know nothing, all veteran users can ignore this orz.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question in the end. It is uninstalling, but it's through the control panel under 'programs and features'. Then I installed through the installer like normal and was able to set up a new email and name for the account I was currently using. Hopefully this will help people who didn't understand the way others put it. I mean, this is more specific for those who are aren't used to uninstalling this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Go to tools -> options,  and remove all authorizations, do not forget to restore access to accounts again. Most likely the problem is related to the expiration of the authorization period.

[link screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RarEU.png)

Comment: Cannot do this as sourcetree crashes immediately, and your fix requires that sourcetree does not crash.

Comment: Previously it was possible to delete a file in the source tree. In my version, I managed to delete the authorization data before closing the program, and this helped

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting these 2 Cache files

- Assemblies.cache
- Composition.cache

in

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_<random_string>\<version_number>
```